# Vectorization of matrix creation by difference of vectors (e.g. for numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

i often need to calculate a matrix `A[i,j]` based on a given vector `v[i]` by:

```
A[i, j] = v[j] - v[i]
```

This is straightforward in a nested loop, but I'd like to vectorize it. So far I've only come up with the rather ugly solution of creating two matrizes additional, where v is repeated in each row/column and I therefore can use simple element-wise matrix addition.

Here a numpy example:

```
import numpy as np
length = 10
v = np.random.random(length)
vjMatrix = np.broadcast_to(v, (length, length))
viMatrix = np.transpose(vjMatrix)

A = vjMatrix - viMatrix
print(A)
```

However, I hope there is a more elegant solution, that I just fail to see. I was looking through a lot of threads, but haven't found anything particularly suitable.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please fill you vectors with some values and a desired output?

Comment: Edited random values in vector, corrected small error and added output of desired matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, you currently fill array `A` like:

```
import numpy as np

length = 100
np.random.seed(123)
v = np.random.rand(length)

vjMatrix = np.broadcast_to(v, (length, length))
viMatrix = np.transpose(vjMatrix)

A = vjMatrix - viMatrix
```

If this is what you want, you can replace the loop and the explicit creation of the `v`-matrices by broadcasting the vector `v`:

```
A_new = v - v[:, None]
print(np.all(A == A_new))
# Out: True
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Do you have some recommended reading source on that broadcasting notation? I don't really understand, what the [:,None] - part does.

Comment: @NegativeJacobian Simply add a new dimension to v (make it 2-D) using [:,None] and let numpy broadcasting do the business.

Comment: You are welcome! Yes, take a look at the [numpy broadcasting documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/theory.broadcasting.html#array-broadcasting-in-numpy). `[:, None]` is the same as `[:, np.newaxis]`, which creates a new axis (enlarges the number of dimensions) and thus allows for flexible operations.

Comment: Thank you very much! One last additional - maybe dumb - question: Sinces this uses the numpy broadcasting capabilites there probably won't be a similar solution e.g. in c++ with std:vectors or other matrix libraries unless they implemented something similar, right?

Comment: Good question and honestly no idea... It's been a long time since I've used c++. But if I remember correctly, there is something similar. I guess this is a good reason to open a new question on stackoverflow. :)